# Is it possible to export a project directly from visual Studio into it's own folder?

Tags: c++, .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-c++

I am currently trying to build .net bindings for a very large project that is written in C an C++. The project was recently ported over to Windows, and I might add that is is a big giant mess.

The solution has about 12 projects, which is fine but the directory itself has alot more files than needed,since it includes OS specific source files, demo projects etc.

Also the other thing is the headers and source files are scattered all over the place. I am working on a parser to help me create the bindings for this project, but I am having a heck of a time. Especially when the internal include references are completely off.

The developer did a great job porting this large project to Windows, but isn't very organized and it is driving me bonkers with the issue my parser is having. So the easiest thing to do would be to re structure and put each project in it's own areas.

So as I asked in the title, is there somewhere that I can export each project and it's files from VS 2010(or another tool) so I can begin restructuring the folders? When I have ever needed to do this before in .net it was easy enough to just move the files. In smaller c++ projects I just open up the project file in notepad++ and move each file in the include/source list into different directories and changed the paths in the project file after. The issue with that is it will take way too long, and I have already spent days messing with this project, finding the best way to wrap it, and creating my helper tools.

Can anyone give me some assistance in this aspect?

**EDIT:Just to clarify, I would like to export each project into it's own root folder with one folder for headers and one for source files so I can keep things simple.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about a tool for this, but the `.vcxproj` project files are in XML format, so you can easily extract a list of files from each project.  Then you could relocate those files and write their new location back into the project.

Whenever I encounter a serious project mess, I usually end up dragging all the project files into Notepad++ and start doing global search and replace.

I haven't done it on the scale that you seem to be aiming at, where it involves relocating all the sources.  You could be in for a rough ride.  Fixing up include paths etc could be quite a pain.

I suggest you obtain the file lists (relative paths or whatever) in a simple text format, and then decide whether you want to take the red pill or the blue pill =)

Comment: Oh, sorry, I missed the bit about how you don't want to use Notepad++.  That was my own example.  What I meant though is you can parse the XML and make your own simple tool to do the heavy lifting.

Comment: Yea I think you are right. I geuss I will continue doing it that way. I appreciate the help. I foundout that visual studio has a template export tool that works with VC++. The only issue is I am not ready to switch over to 2012.